# File's owner missing

Tags: ios, xcode

In tutorial files owner interface with delegate and datasource can seen. But in my xcode 7.0 I cant see file's owner or any option to visible it. I think there is another method in this xcode version. Plz suggest something.
Here I can see file's owner below place holder
[image]

Here is different format
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In second format, drag to View Controller object (with yellow icon).